# can not fetch image from the backend in nuxtjs

Tags: api, axios, nuxt.js

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                     <div> <img style="width:500px; height:350px" 
 
 
 :src="`${this.$axios.defaults.baseURL}/api/v1/articles/5fcb69018823ce3e7881ceb6/preview/preview_5fc4e5a43fb595393c203e19.jpg`" alt=""></div>
              </div>##
```

how to fetch image with axios in nuxtjs please can tell me?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read this blog post about how to get good answers: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There is no seem to be problem with the syntax. You can paste here the full URL you are trying to fetch?